# UIView disappears after applying CATransform3DRotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, catransform3d

How to determine whether value for angle of rotation of UIView is perpendicular to Y-axis or to restrict the angle of rotation to only quarter of the circle instead of whole 360 rotation.
  I have a UIView with the below applied CATransformation,.

```
    t = CATransform3DIdentity;
    //Add the perspective!!!
    t.m34 = 1.0/ 300;
    t = CATransform3DRotate(t, 45.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 0, 1, 0);
    self.containerView.layer.sublayerTransform = t;
```

like in this [link1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5dk5wqf3vpu4js/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-16%20at%206.51.50%20pm.png)
 and changing the rotation angles based on UIPanGesture in the space outside of the rotated UIView with below code

```
    - (void)handleRevealGestureStateChangedWithRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
//Calculating percent of translation.
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view.superview];
CGFloat rotationpercent = translation.x / recognizer.view.frame.size.width;
[self rotate:rotationpercent];     //calling method to transform based on translation value
```

}

```
- (void)rotate:(CGFloat)rotateDegress{
CGFloat angle =  M_PI * rotateDegress;
t = CATransform3DRotate(t, angle, 0, 1, 0);
self.containerView.layer.sublayerTransform = t;
```

}

this rotates the view and for certain angles the view is either perpendicular to Y-axis on further it goes beyond window to rotate in full 360 degrees like shown in this [link2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnahw4pxe0xanfz/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%2016-Apr-2014%207.16.13%20pm.png).

Hence is it possible to determine if the angle is exceeding 90 degree so that rotation is disabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using angles in degrees, which is fine (since you convert to radians before applying a rotation.)

Just put code in your gesture recognizer that limits the angles to a range of 0 to ~85 degrees. (Experiment with the upper limit to see how close to 90% you can get before the page is too thin to maintain the illusion of depth.) Problem solved.

Comment: Duncan,thanks for the solution but the problem I faced here is since the rotation angle values are computated from pan gesture,there seems multiple arbitrary values ranging differently from 0.122235,0.090892 ,0.007812 for the UIView to appear perpendicular to Y-axis.So it seems not possible to determine the limit closer as you had suggested.

Comment: IN your second block of code you use the gesture recognizer to calculate rotationpercent, but then you don't use that to calculate rotateDegress. If rotateDegress degrees is a stack variable it likely contains garbage, and so you are getting semi-random results. (Unless there's code you did not post)

Comment: Yes,pardon me for I missed to comment that in my second block of code, the calculated 'rotationpercent' from gesture recogniser was passed as a parameter to a method to apply translation and assigned to variable name 'rotateDegress'. So rotateDegress is not a stack variable to contain garbage values.

Comment: Ok, but the devil is in the details. You almost certainly have a bug in the code that calculates the rotation angle in degrees and/or the conversion from degrees to radians. You need to post the code exactly as it is running, since this is the code that likely contains a bug. We can't help debug code we can't see. I would suggest making your code calculate the final radians value in a temporary variable. Then add a log statement to log that value as you apply it (or use a breakpoint action to log the value so you can turn it off.)

Comment: Duncan,I've edited the question by adding the complete code of getting
rotation degrees in pan gesture translation (2nd code block)and using that value in transforming the view (3rd code block).

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense to me. You're calling `[self rotate:rotationpercent]`, and passing in a percent value, that presumably ranges from 0 to 1. Then you're using it as if its degrees? Your code is also applying the new angle value to the existing transform, which makes the rotation cumulative. You don't want to do that.